# initiate auto click of file input in on init of ts of component using angular typescript

Tags: html, angular, file

I have this file input in html part of component.

```
<input type="file" />
```

This component is dialog and I want to simulate click on that input inside `ngOnInit()` function so when the dialog opens users proceeds to choose file directly without hitting choose file button. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" #dummyClick/>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('dummyClick') dummyClickRef: ElementRef;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dummyClickRef.nativeElement.click()
}
```

Comment: I don't think this works for file inputs from ngOnInit, althought I could be wrong. I think it has to be in response to a user action or the browser will ignore it.

Comment: where should I write this? >  @ViewChild('dummyClick') dummyClickRef: ElementRef;
I get errors if I put it in ts : cannot find name 'ViewChild'

Comment: @Jacquesジャックit is working i just implement this in my recent project :)

Comment: @David I just update my answer pls check. you only need to import the `ViewChild`